# Malloc, free, and realloc behaviour in C

Tags: c, malloc, free, realloc

I have to recode these 3 functions in C and the goal is that the recoded functions have to replace the system functions in different programs or system calls.

I don't really understand what is the behaviour of these functions since I've read the mans, I just know I'm allowed to use `brk()` and `sbrk()`.

Comment: There are thousands of examples of memory allocators using those two system calls if you just search a little.

Comment: Clearly you're taking some kind of course or class on this. You need to check out your teaching materials, this should be covered. Nobody would point students at the man pages only and expect them to write a heap allocator from scratch based on the information in them.

Comment: Have you read the man pages for `brk` and `sbrk` too? Is there something there that is not clear? What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: Yes i'm in a school, but don't have any indications from the teachers. It's a school based on self learning only..

Comment: @skyking I've understood the man of `brk()` and `sbrk()` but I don't see how i can handle the multiple types

Comment: I think you should elaborate a little more in the question. For example what you have done so far. The task of implementing these function is no easy coffe-break-task, there much to be done implementing them and going through all steps are simply to much for one question. Perhaps you could write down the actual assignment (if you got it in writing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc` basically pre allocates memory pages (Cf `getpagesize(2)`), and returns pointer to usable parts of those pre allocated areas when called.
`malloc` then have to "remember" which part of those pre allocated memory segments are being used, and which one are free.
Reading this article: https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/look-at-how-malloc-works-on-mac.html might help! (I know it was great help to me when i re-coded malloc on mac Os as an university assignment ;)).